# messageChannel folder in VS Code

Tags: vs-code, lightning-message-service

Should the messageChannel folder be automatically created when I create new sfdx manifest project in VS Code? Or should I create it manually?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For now (Summer 20/sfdx 7.73.1), sfdx nor VS Code will not automatically be created at this time. If you need it, you can create it.

Comment: Can i create message channel from ui setup?

Comment: @IanRoque Until the documentation says you can, you can't. As far as I can tell, there's nothing in the upcoming release notes about this, so it's going to be at least a bit longer.